# Flink 1.13.2 HA with K8s

Tags: kubernetes, apache-flink, high-availability

By following [Kubernetes HA Services](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/deployment/ha/kubernetes_ha/) I added the setup in my setting, but when i try to deploy Flink job, the error msg is :

```
Caused by: io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: configmaps "flink-app-cluster-my-application-restserver-leader" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:streaming:flink-svc-acc-my-application" cannot watch resource "configmaps" in API group "" in the namespace "default"
```

After searching for a while, here is probably the answer to the issue:

1. Setup [kuberntes.namespace](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/deployment/config/#kubernetes-namespace) to the one you are using, in my case: streaming
2. Make sure the service account has access right to configMap in that namespace, if not, use Role and RoleBinding to create one, in my case flink-svc-acc-my-application has access right.

Comment: In Flink doc, it only mentioned that to set all the HA setup, but it didn't mention to setup kuberntes.namespace, which gives me some headache.

Comment: To quickly summarize it
1) Setup Kubernetes.namespace to the namespace you run instead of "default"
2) Setup Role and RoleBinding for the service account to give access right of configmaps
3) In the https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/deployment/resource-providers/standalone/kubernetes/ the HA vs non HA jobmanager.yaml file has POD_IP section difference, can not ignore.

Comment: The error message says explicitly that you need to grant your service account with access to the `default` namespace and your client specifically needs the ability to `watch` `configmap` objects in it.

Comment: the issue is that the service account should not access to default namespace, the service account should have the ability to watch configmap in its own namespace. That's basically what it boils down to.